# FreeBSD: OpenLDAP, SASL, and GSSAPI

Tags: ldap, freebsd, openldap, kerberos, sasl

I've run into some problems getting OpenLDAP on FreeBSD (8.2-STABLE) to authenticate using Kerberos tickets.  I hope I've just had a brain glitch, so please feel free to let me know that I've missed something obvious.

Here's where things are:

- Kerberos works just fine.

  I can acquire credentials using `kinit`, and I can use these credentials for authentication (for example, for ssh or telnet login).
- OpenLDAP is installed and works with basic authentication.
- slapd is clearly linked against the SASL libraries; `ldd .../slapd` reports:

  ```
  libsasl2.so.2 => /usr/local/lib/libsasl2.so.2 (0x800d07000)
  ```
- There exists /usr/local/lib/sasl2/slapd.conf with the following contents:

  ```
  mech_list: GSSAPI
  ```
- slapd reports that is supports GSSAPI authentication:

  ```
  $ ldapsearch -x -b '' -s base supportedSASLMechanisms
  dn:
  supportedSASLMechanisms: GSSAPI
  ```
- There exists `/etc/krb5.keytab` with keys for `host/<myhostname>` and `ldap/<myhostname>`.
- The sample SASL server/client appear to work fine with gssapi authentication:

  ```
  # server -p 2222 -s ldap -m gssapi
  ```

  Followed by:

  ```
  # client -p 2222 -s ldap -m gssapi
  ```

  Ultimately results in:

  ```
  successful authentication
  ```

And yet...

I have been unable to get slapd to accept GSSAPI authentication.  Simply trying to run `ldapwhoami`, with a valid Kerberos ticket, results in the following error:

```
SASL/GSSAPI authentication started
ldap_sasl_interactive_bind_s: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
    additional info: SASL(-1): generic failure: GSSAPI Error:  No credentials were supplied, or the credentials were unavailable or inaccessible. (unknown mech-code 0 for mech unknown)
```

The same error is logged by `slapd`.  I've sort of hit a wall here; slapd even with various debugging turned on isn't providing me with anything useful.  Help?

*Update*:  Just for kicks I decided to try setting up OpenLDAP inside a Linux (CentOS 5) jail to see if the behavior was any different.  After rebuilding the OpenLDAP packages (FreeBSD's Linux support does not include the `epoll()` system call), it was giving me error messages that seemed a little more useful (regarding missing Kerberos principals).  It at least seemed to be performing the GSSAPI negotiation correctly.  So it looks like this is a FreeBSD issue...maybe?  Hoping for input from somebody out there.

Answer (score 1):

And...mysteriously it's started working.   For the record, here is what seems to be a repeatable process:

- Install security/cyrus-sasl2.
- Install net/openldap24-server.  Make sure to enable SASL support.
- Install net/openlda24-client, also with SASL support.
- Initialize Kerberos per [the handbook](http://www.freebsd.org/doc/handbook/kerberos5.html).  Make sure to add the appropriate `ldap/...` principal.
- Make sure slapd will be able to read a keytab file.  The simplest mechanism is:

  ```
  chgrp ldap /etc/krb5.keytab
  chmod g+r /etc/krb5.keytab
  ```
- Configure slapd for SASL.  You will probably want to set `sasl-host`, `sasl-realm`, and `sasl-regexp`.
- Configure appropriate values for `BASE` and `URI` in `/usr/local/etc/openldap/ldap.conf`.

Test by acquiring a Kerberos ticket and then running `ldapwhoami -Y GSSAPI`.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and in the end found out it was because I had set sasl-host in slapd.conf to be the kerberos server hostname.

When I changed sasl-host to be ldap hostname (e.g. sasl-host ldap.example.com) it worked correctly.